# Does a combination of OfType() and FirstOrDefault() iterate over the entire array?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have an array of BaseTool and I want to return the first element of type T:

```
public BaseTool GetTool<T>() where T : BaseTool
{
    foreach (var tool in tools)
    {
        if (tool is T)
        {
            return tool;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Rider suggested me to use LINQ methods instead:

```
public BaseTool GetTool<T>() where T : BaseTool
{
    return tools.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I was wondering if these two imeplementations will perform the same. The basic loop variant returns upon finding the first T instance. I know that OfType uses deferred execution. But I'm not sure if the above combination with FirstOrDefault will cause the evaluation of OfType on the entire array or not.

Comment: _"if the above combination with FirstOrDefault will cause the evaluation of OfType on the entire array"_ Probably not (I don't have a source). If you're in doubt, maybe you can use `tools.FirstOrDefault(x => x is T);` instead?

Comment: [`OfType` uses `yield return`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Cast.cs#L12-L31), so it won't exhaust the collection when combined with `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` only iterates as far as it needs to (finding the first element) - so no, this won't cause the whole sqeuence to be evaluated, unless there are no elements of that type (or it's just the last element).

More details are in my [Edulinq blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions/), or you can look at the [.NET Core implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/First.cs) - which is slightly more complex than my Edulinq implementation, but still lazy (unless you have an `IList<T>` implementation with a terribly-implemented `Count` property, or something like that).